# Constructor not defined: [AccountsWithCheckbox.WrapAccountCheckbox].<Constructor>(Boolean, String, Account)

Tags: trigger

```
public class AccountsWithCheckbox {
    public List<WrapAccountCheckbox> lstAcc{set;get;}
    public AccountsWithCheckbox(){
        lstAcc=new List<WrapAccountCheckbox>();
        List<Account> accList= new List<Account>([select id,name,Active__c,SLAExpirationDate__c,SLA__c from Account]);

        for(Integer i=0;i<accList.size();i++){
            boolean check=false;
            if(accList[i].Active__c=='yes'){
                check=true;
            }
            WrapAccountCheckbox abc=new WrapAccountCheckbox(check,String.valueOf((i+1)),accList[i]);
            lstAcc.add(abc);
           // lstAcc.add(new WrapAccountCheckbox(String.valueOf(i+1),accList[i]));
        }
    }

    public class WrapAccountCheckbox{
        public Account acc{set;get;}
        public String sNo {set;get;}
        public boolean checkbox{set;get;}

        public WrapAccountCheckbox(){

        }

        public WrapAccountCheckbox(String s,Account a,boolean b){
            this.checkbox=b;
            this.sNo=s;
            this.acc=a;

        }

        public WrapAccountCheckbox(String s,Account a){
             this.sNo=s;
             this.acc=a;
             checkbox=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing values in constructor like (Boolean, String, Account) and you have created constructor with (String, Account, boolean). Change order of values while creating object of WrapAccountCheckbox.

```
  WrapAccountCheckbox abc=new WrapAccountCheckbox(check,accList[i],String.valueOf((i+1)));
```

`